# as3 worker with 1009 TypeError for unknown reason

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3

I'm working on a AS3 script where I try to start a thread. I keep getting the 1009 error below when I try. I'm following a howto page from the internet pretty closely. I'm using (I think) version 11.4 of flash.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
object reference.
```

This refers to the line where swfBytes is assigned this.loaderInfo.bytes.

```
package somepackage {

    import flash.system.MessageChannel;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class SomeClass  extends Sprite{

        public var mainToWorker:MessageChannel;
        public var workerToMain:MessageChannel;
        public var worker:Worker;



        public function SomeClass() {
            // constructor code

            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) {
                var swfBytes:ByteArray = this.loaderInfo.bytes;// HERE

                worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker( swfBytes );
                mainToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);
                workerToMain = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);

                worker.setSharedProperty("mainToWorker", mainToWorker);
                worker.setSharedProperty("workerToMain", workerToMain);

                //workerToMain.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMain);

                //worker.start();
            }
            else {
                mainToWorker = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("mainToWorker");
                workerToMain = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMain");

                //mainToWorker.addEventListener("mainToWorker", onMainToWorker);
            }


        }

    }


}
```

If anyone has seen this before or knows what I'm doing wrong I'd be most appreciative.

I'm instantiating this as part of a much larger group of classes. I thought that might be my problem, so I instantiated this class on it's own at the 'actions' script page of the root scene. I'm using Flash CS6. There is not much on the 'actions' page I was referring to.

```
var ai:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
addChild(ai);
```

EDIT 1:
Here I've included a 'addEventListener' line. This code seems to work in debug mode but not if I just play the movie regularly. If I play it regularly I get the 1009 error again, presumably for the line after the trace. What could I replace 'Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE' with that would allow this to run??

```
package somepackage {

    public class SomeClass extends Sprite{

        public var mainToWorker:MessageChannel;
        public var workerToMain:MessageChannel;
        public var worker:Worker;

        public function SomeClass() {

            if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) {

                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            }

        }

        public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            trace(this.loaderInfo);

            var swfBytes:ByteArray = this.loaderInfo.bytes;

            worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker( swfBytes );

            mainToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);
            workerToMain = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);

            worker.setSharedProperty("mainToWorker", mainToWorker);
            worker.setSharedProperty("workerToMain", workerToMain);

            workerToMain.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMain);

            worker.start();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but try adding the new keyword?
var ai:SomeClass = new SomeClass();

Comment: ah yes, that's a typo. I'll fix that now.

Comment: Most likely this.loaderInfo is null, so you can not access the bytes property. Trace it out before the broken line:
`trace(this.loaderInfo);`

Comment: yes, trace(this.loaderInfo) just says 'null'

Comment: I edited my original question a little. Now, when I run the program in debug mode it seems to work, and if I run it in normal mode it doesn't. I added an event listener to `this.loaderInfo` that waits for `Event.Complete` but the result is the same. The debugger works and the regular run doesn't.